# NSURLConnection Error : "Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to make an API call with `NSURLConnection`. Along with that I'm passing my json data to the server in `POST` request. But its ends with following error at the end,

> No usable value for user
>
> Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String

I'm not sure what does it mean?

This is what `NSURLResponse` prints in console:

> { status code: 400, headers {
>       "Content-Length" = 88;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Fri, 03 Jul 2015 11:20:10 GMT";
>       Server = "spray-can/1.3.2"; } }

For security reasons, I'm not able to add a link to my API.

Here's the code for this API call:

```
NSNumber *actionInNumber = @(5);

NSDictionary *characteristics = @{@"ratings":actionInNumber};

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"eName":@"rating",
                             @"eType":@"user",
                             @"eID":@"1234567890",
                             @"targetEType":@"item",
                             @"targetEId":@"0987654321",
                             @"characteristics":characteristics,
                             @"eTime":@"03-07-2015"};

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/q.json?accessKey=someUniqueKeyToAccessToThisAPICall"]];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
 ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
     if(!connectionError) {
         NSLog(@"%@", response);
         NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
     }
 }];
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In my opinion, the best answer would be one that came from whoever is responsible for the server.  That's who should know what is expected, what was received, and what the difference is.  That being said, the message ("No usable value for user") sounds like it expects "user" to be a key rather than a value...but I'm only guessing based on what I would mean if I wrote that message.  :)

Comment: @PhillipMills, Thanks, yes, I agree. But there's one field we're passing with request is `eType` and I'm passing "user" in that. I think, I'm missing something at my end? I don't even know whether the request is went properly or not as it doesn't showing any error in `connectionError` object (of `NSError`).

Comment: That's part of why I think it's a difference between server expectations and what you're sending as data.  There wouldn't be any networking errors if everything transmits OK and it's only the server rejecting the contents.  (I saw that you were sending "user" as a value; I was saying that maybe it should be a key instead...or in addition?)

Comment: @PhillipMills, thanks again. I'll check this out with my server guy first.